# ServerSocket.accept() terminates the Android Application

Tags: java, android, sockets, communication, serversocket

guys. I'm new to Android and the forum. I have the following problem which bothers me about socket communication.

```
package com.example.d5server2;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView textview1;
    Button button1;
    ServerSocket serversocket1 = null;
    Socket socket1 = null;
    int i=16;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

        try {
            serversocket1 = new ServerSocket(9999);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            socket1 = serversocket1.accept();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

When I run this code on my phone the application gets terminated. Yet if I delete the line

```
socket1 = serversocket1.accept();
```

it doesn't do so. I checked many sample codes and most of them used a similar coding. I can't find any reasons why my app gets terminated. I search the web but couldn't get any answer for this. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: What errors do you get in your logs?

Comment: Is an exception being thrown?

Comment: I don't get any exceptions I just know that my app gets terminated at start

Comment: Maybe no privileges in manifest? `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: I added the permission. I think I'm missing a simple point as I'm a beginner. Do you think of any simple mistakes that could lead to this?

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, because you haven't provided enough information such as a stack trace, 'serverSocket' is probably null, because your incorrect exception handling allows the application to continue even if the initialization of the ServerSocket threw an exception.